# Meaning of X in Oracle Timestamp Format 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'

Tags: oracle, timestamp, oracle18c

Recently, I came across this function `TO_TIMESTAMP('20-JUL-16 02.25.43.024273000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM')`. I could not find any reference regarding what `X` means.

What is the meaning of `X` in the timestamp format `DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM`?

Comment: Search for "Oracle 18c TO_TIMESTAMP" and that gets you to the [documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TO_TIMESTAMP.html#GUID-57E09334-E3CC-4CA2-809E-F0909458BCFA) then at the bottom of the page is a link to [Datetime Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A) where there is a list of all the format elements, including `X`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's *local radix character*. See documentation for [Format models](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210).

What's that?

> In mathematics and computing, a radix point (or radix character) is the symbol used in numerical representations to separate the integer part of a number (to the left of the radix point) from its fractional part (to the right of the radix point).